# Constructor and destructor calls when pushing on to a C++ vector

Tags: c++, constructor, destructor

For the following code

```
struct MyInt {

  MyInt() { 
    std::cout << "I am the constructor for " << val << "\n";
  }
  ~MyInt() {
    std::cout << "I am the destructor for " << val << "\n";
  }

  int val;

};

int main() {

    using namespace std;

    cout << "Constructing l:" << endl;

    vector<MyInt /*, Mallocator<MyInt>*/ > l;

    MyInt int1;
    MyInt int2;
    int1.val = 1729;
    int2.val = 2161;

    cout << "Push back the item\n";

    l.push_back(int1);
    l.push_back(int2);

  return 0;
}
```

Why I get the following outputs?

```
Constructing l:
I am the constructor for 1558899544 (garbage)
I am the constructor for 47517696 (garbage)
Push back the item
I am the destructor for 1729
I am the destructor for 2161
I am the destructor for 1729
I am the destructor for 1729
I am the destructor for 2161
```

I was assuming to have four constructors (two for int1 and int2, two for push_back) and four destructors. Having five destructors surprises me.

Comment: Put in `"I am the destructor for " << val << std::endl` for more insight.

Comment: You forgot to trace copy and move constructors.

Comment: The garbage values are there because the constructor runs before the `val` is set. You are printing the value of a member variable that hasn't been initialized (which probably yields undefined behavior).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You see only two "`I am the constructor for...`" because you forgot to add the copy constructor:

```
MyInt(const MyInt& rhs) 
{ 
    std::cout << "I am the constructor copy\n";
    val = rhs.val;
}
```

You see 5 destructors because of reallocation, as *Barry* mentioned in his answer. You can `reserve` the size on your vector and you will see only the 4 destructors you expected:

```
l.reserve(2); // 2 will suffice for the example at hand
```

Adding that to your code *may* output (as pointed out by *PaulMcKenzie*, compilers are free to remove copy construction, so the final output can depend on compiler, compiler settings, optimizations):

```
Constructing l:
I am the constructor default
I am the constructor default
Push back the item
I am the constructor copy
I am the constructor copy
I am the destructor
I am the destructor
I am the destructor
I am the destructor
```

Comment: "*your code should output:*" --  That should be *may output*.  Compilers are free to remove copy construction, so the final output can depend on compiler, compiler settings, optimizations, etc.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie indeed, added it as clarification

Answer (score 0):

Five destructors:

- Two each for `int1` and `int2` in `main()`
- One for the object inside of `l`, when it had to get reallocated to accommodate more members.
- Two for the `MyInt`s held by `l`.

Comment: @Jes It doesn't default construct them though. It copies them, and you didn't instrument `MyInt(MyInt const&)`.